# How to I export transaction log of MS SQL 2008 database?

Tags: sql-server

How do I export / view changes between 3:00am and 8:30am on my database?  I have people entering data to the server and during that time, we had an issue where people data were not properly entered into the system.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a good discussion of the issue in [this forum post](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1019240-357-1.aspx).  The bottom line is  transaction logs are not meant for reviewing what happened but are part of the internal working of SQL and disaster recovery. Most importantly you cannot find out who did what from a transaction log.  You need auditing enabled for that.

There is a link to this [3rd party tool](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx) that may help.

Answer (score 0):

Not much help in 2011 - but if you are using SQL Server 2000 only, there's a free (and hence very limited support) version by Redgate:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-log-rescue/

Answer (score 0):

[Ajit Ananthram's blog post](http://ajitananthram.wordpress.com/2012/05/26/auditing-external-activator/) covers the options (Change Tracking, Change Data Capture, Service Broker with External Activator) in detail.

Comment: Providing a link with details is good, but including a basic overview on what to do to accomplish the goal is more helpful to OP.